# Hardware timer , Real time clock, Jiffies in Linux context

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, interrupt, clock

I am trying to understand the Timer interrupts and the associated terms used in an `x86_64 Linux` machine.

1. Hardware timer (External clock) is same as a `Real Time Clock`.
2. The Real time clock runs even when the CPU is in `off` state and update the time when it restarts. If that is the only duty of an `RTC`, is there a need for this clock to interrupt once the machine is running?
3. Jiffies are software timer interrupts used in process scheduling and the OS specific timer requirements.

Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. A hardware timer is not necessarily the same as an RTC. What defines an RTC is its ability to track the time while the system is off. It also often comes with an alarm that allows waking up or restarting the system.
2. This is correct. There is no strict need for the interrupt. However, if you care about time accuracy you need this interrupt because it is the only way to accurately read an RTC as this allows to know exactly when the second is updated. Also an RTC will drift way less than the usual CPU counter that is used to track the system time.
3. jiffies represent an amount of time and are updated using a timer. It is very likely to be backed by an high resolution timer on a recent enough platform.